# Having trouble with getting basic auth from play framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, basic-authentication

I have `request.headers.get("Authorization")` but I still don't receive anything other than `none`

```
def test = Action { request =>
    Ok("Here " + request.headers.get("Authorization") + " there")
}
```

I would like to be able to parse the basic auth, but since I currently don't even receive it its kind of a mute point.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing request.headers.getHeaders() (which produces a map) and loop through the map, printing all Key,Value pairs to see if it is truly missing.